# How do I run a superhero game in GURPS lite 4th edition?

Tags: gurps-4e, supers

I was planning on making a superhero game for my friend who is new to RPGS in GURPS lite and realized that there was a *severe* lack of superhero powers. Yes, "Jumper" is a very superhero power but I asked him about that and he said that it wasn't really his style.

I will note that I *do* have access to other materials **BUT** it's limited to what ever I can realistically print off on a home printer. I don't have very much money, so that's a problem.

So, my question is how can I bring more "superhero" powers into my game?

Comment: GURPS Lite is the "taster" version of the rules. Since you want more than what's in that taste, is there any reason why you're not just getting the full GURPS core book?

Comment: GURPS Powers is the source book you really need, but you'd need the full Basic Set (both volumes) and possibly other source books to use it properly.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly the 4th ed lite rules dropped the magic section from 3rd ed.

So go get the [GURPS 3th edition lite rules](http://www.sjgames.com/gurps/lite/3e/) and plunder the Magic section (p30-31). You have enough there to create the Human Torch (all the fire spells), Iceman (instead of fire use ice), Wolverine (continuous Minor healing), Quicksilver (Haste), ...